# Perl DBI one connection from different objects: problems

Tags: sql, perl, database-connection, dbi

In my script it creates several different objects that use a wrapper for DBI:

```
package MY::DB;
use DBI;

sub my_connect {
  my ($class, %p) = @_;
  my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
  $dbh->do("SET NAMES cp1251");
  return bless {dbh => $dbh}, $class;
}

sub query {
  my ($self, $sql) = @_;
  # sql execution
}
...
```

I decided to optimize the script using only one connection to the database. Tried two options: a global variable and a method of DBI->connect_cached(..). The result is the same: the connection is actually used one for all objects, but does not process the SQL code after connection:

```
...
sub my_connect {
  my ($class, %p) = @_;
  my $dbh = DBI->connect_cached(...);
  $dbh->do("SET NAMES cp1251"); # no effect :(
  return bless {dbh => $dbh}, $class;
}
...
```

For example I have classes:

```
package MY::USER;
use base 'MY::DB';
sub constructor {
    my ($class) = @_;
    return MY::DB::my_connect($class);
}
sub get_info_1 {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $self->query(...);
}
sub get_info_2 {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $self->query();
}

package MY::NEWS;
use base 'MY::DB';
sub constructor {
    my ($class) = @_;
    return MY::DB::my_connect($class);
}
sub get_info {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $self->query(...);
}
```

Script:

```
use MY::USER;
use MY::NEWS;

my $user = MY::USER->constructor;
my $news = MY::NEWS->constructor;

$user->get_info_1; # OK
$news->get_info; # OK
$user->get_info_2; # here $dbh->do("set names cp1251") operation no effect
```

Comment: Yes, but it is wrapper (agregation) for DBI, not a subclass...

Comment: if I use connect_cached() then do("set names...") have not effect (not for all objects)

Comment: What database? Minimal code to replicate?

Comment: mysql 5.1; now I see what it take effect with no all objects...

Comment: Yes, but we can't see. Please provide minimal code to demonstrate the problem. Don't make us guess what your code is.

Comment: updated description of the problem

Comment: First of all, what you posted can be boiled down to 6 lines. That's hardly minimal. It's also rather useless. You're trying to demonstrate a database problem, but keep posting everything but the database code. More importantly, even you did include data and queries, it still wouldn't demonstrate any lack of effect of `set names`. Don't say it has no effect, demonstrate it having no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer on my problem!

Main DBI-class has destructor:

```
sub DESTROY {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->{dbh}->disconnect;
}
```

And all childs of this class have it. 
Inside NEWS->get_info() called and destroyed same objects, and link to database disconnected... but value of DBH variable is defined!